# Php Counter Hides Comma after loading and not showing permanently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to figure out a php counter. I have added Number format in a php function to print counter digits separated with a comma after first 3 digits. But Comma doesn't show up permanently after page load, When I reload the page, Comma shows for a moment but immediately hides. Below is the code i have used to get this result and please review the counter page.

```
<?php
$bg = get_field('counter_bg');

$init_value = get_field('init_value');
$init_date = get_field('init_date');
$seconds = strtotime("now") - strtotime($init_date);
$countup_value = get_field('countup_value');
$number = round((($seconds * $countup_value) + $init_value) * 100) / 100;

if($number) :
  $title = get_field('counter_title');
  $text = get_field('counter_text');
  ?>
  <section class="home-section" id="home-counter" <?php if($bg['url']) echo "style='background-image: url({$bg['sizes']['slide-thumb']})'"; ?>>
    <div class="container">
      <?php
      if($title) echo "<h3 class='counter-title'>{$title}</h3>";
      echo "<div id='counter-number'>";
      echo Number_format ($number);
      echo "</div>";
      if($text) echo "<div class='counter-text'>{$text}</div>";
      ?>

    </div><!--containr-->
  </section><!--home-section-->

  <script>
    (function($) {

      $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = $('#counter-number');
        var coutUp = Number(<?= $countup_value ?>);

        setInterval(function() {
          counter.text(calculate_value);
        }, 1000)

        function calculate_value() {
          var initDate = moment('<?= $init_date ?>').format('x');
          var nowDate = moment().format('x');
          var dif = Number((nowDate - initDate) / 1000);
          var value = Number(dif * coutUp);
          // console.log(initDate, nowDate, dif, value, '<?= $init_date ?>');
          return value.toFixed(2)

        }

      });

    })(jQuery);
  </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Please check the current Comman display issue at: http://airlite.designase.com/it/

Comment: Hard to replicate just like that. However, you see that you have a Javascript timeout function right? A second after page load, you executed a JS code.

Comment: The javascript will not apply the number format, that's why you need to format on javascript

Answer (score 0):

Now it should keep the comma. You can set the number of decimals by changing the (2) parameter in toFixed() function in the end of the JS function.

```
<?php
$bg = get_field('counter_bg');

$init_value = get_field('init_value');
$init_date = get_field('init_date');
$seconds = strtotime("now") - strtotime($init_date);
$countup_value = get_field('countup_value');
$number = round((($seconds * $countup_value) + $init_value) * 100) / 100;

if($number) :
  $title = get_field('counter_title');
  $text = get_field('counter_text');
  ?>
  <section class="home-section" id="home-counter" <?php if($bg['url']) echo "style='background-image: url({$bg['sizes']['slide-thumb']})'"; ?>>
    <div class="container">
      <?php
      if($title) echo "<h3 class='counter-title'>{$title}</h3>";
      echo "<div id='counter-number'>";
      echo Number_format ($number);
      echo "</div>";
      if($text) echo "<div class='counter-text'>{$text}</div>";
      ?>

    </div><!--containr-->
  </section><!--home-section-->

  <script>
    (function($) {

      $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = $('#counter-number');
        var coutUp = Number(<?= $countup_value ?>);

        setInterval(function() {
          counter.text(calculate_value);
        }, 1000)

        function calculate_value() {
          var initDate = moment('<?= $init_date ?>').format('x');
          var nowDate = moment().format('x');
          var dif = Number((nowDate - initDate) / 1000);
          var value = Number(dif * coutUp);
          // console.log(initDate, nowDate, dif, value, '<?= $init_date ?>');
          return value.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")
        }

      });

    })(jQuery);
  </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: After making this value an integer (Removing Decimal Numbers) I want to keep comma after 3 digits front start.

Comment: Tell me what my suggestion resulted in, so I can fix it accordingly. Tested my solution? @ManishBajpai

Comment: Its working now, But having another issue, If add .replace(".", ",") function then it forcefully changes the value from "128937" to a big difference "128912". It means it is pulling wrong values due to any issues. Please help me. Correct Value showing here: [http://www.airlite.com/] and testing value is here [http://airlite.designase.com/it/]

Comment: I found it working correctly using return function 'return value.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");' recommended by @claudio

Answer (score 0):

According to the php `number_format`, you want to group the number by thousands. You can to that by changing the return of the `calculate_value` function like this:

```
return value.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

The regex will add a comma every 3 digits, like this:

```js
   (function($) {

      $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = $('#counter-number');
        var coutUp = Number(1);

        setInterval(function() {
          counter.text(calculate_value);
        }, 1000)

        function calculate_value() {
          var initDate = moment(20111031).format('x');
          var nowDate = moment().format('x');
          var dif = Number((nowDate - initDate) / 1000);
          var value = Number(dif * coutUp);
          // console.log(initDate, nowDate, dif, value, '<?= $init_date ?>');
          return value.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }

      });

    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="counter-number"></span>
```